# Symfony2 Dependency Injection Service Scoping Performance

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

From a purely Performance perspective, is there any difference between `request` and `container` scoping services?

The reason I ask is because I am writing a few services that end up gathering the definitions of some tagged services via a compiler pass. Now this holder service doesn't actually contain the Definition (as that would require the ProxyManager and lazy services), just the service ID.

However if a definition is retrieved from the holder, it can lead to errors if one of the tagged services it holds is dependant on another request scoped service.

The simple solution is `request` scope the holder, but is that efficient?